# REST API update group owner using a workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, groups

How can I change the group owner of a group by a sharepoint workflow using the REST api?

I am creating the group by a rest call in the workflow. This works perfectly but the owner is set to the user running the workflow.

What I have tried so far:

- Adding an "Owner" parameter with a paylod of `{"Id":"15"}`. The workflow runs with no errors but the owner field is not updated
- Hitting the `/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById([GroupId])/Owner` endpoint but it seems it doesn't exist

Judging by [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_Group) the Owner parameter should be writeable, but it does not seem to work.

BTW I'm working on SharePoint Online.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for it?

Comment: Not really - I had to make all members able to edit the group membership. And running the workflow with elevated app permissions would make the app the owner and not the user running the workflow.

Comment: I managed to have a workaround by using the `client.svc/ProcessQuery` [approach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-csom/18c961c7-8384-4493-8227-54a3fffdc7cc). Check this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2dcf6e49-cff8-403b-b52e-04d240bef16d/set-group-owner-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it isn't possible.

For those who have the same problem please vote the feature in user voice:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/11503626-add-the-possibility-to-set-the-owner-when-creating